# PHP error during SELECT on prepared statement (fetch_assoc() function)

Tags: php, mysqli

this is a common problem, but i already did my research and I couldn't find a solution. SO here I am.

The error i am getting is : **Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object**

Firstly I have the mysqlnd enabled. Secondly My query does not have an error. I am being able to run it in the phpmyadmin with no problems.

**Here is the query thats is being run:**

```
SELECT * FROM photos WHERE name LIKE '%ait%' 
UNION 
SELECT photos.* FROM photos, photo_tag, tags 
WHERE photo_tag.photo_id = photos.id 
AND photo_tag.tag_id = tags.id 
AND tags.name IN('ait')
```

**And here is the code where the error happens (more specifically in the fetch_assoc() function):**

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
if($stmt){
    $stmt->execute();
    while($row = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc()){
        $photo = new Photo(null, null, null, null);
        $photo->id=$row["id"];
        $photo->userId=$row["user_id"];
        $photo->name = $row["name"];
        $photo->photoPath=$row["photo_path"];
        $result[] = $photo;
    }
    return $result;
}else{
    var_dump($this->db->error);
}
```

If you guys could help me with this I would be very grateful.

Comment: use LEFT JOIN instead of FROM table1, table2, table3. The problem is in your SQL query

Comment: @EduardVoid its not. There are tho ways of making a JOIN. Using JOIN or the way I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only call `get_result()` once, not every time through the loop.

```
$stmt->execute();
$stmt_result = $stmt->get_result();
while($row = $stmt_result->fetch_assoc()){
    $photo = new Photo(null, null, null, null);
    $photo->id=$row["id"];
    $photo->userId=$row["user_id"];
    $photo->name = $row["name"];
    $photo->photoPath=$row["photo_path"];
    $result[] = $photo;
}
```